# Dependency injection, differences?

Tags: swift, dependency-injection

I have trying to figure if there's any difference between injecting dependencies through the initializer by directly injecting the dependency or by injecting a dependency that conforms to a protocol?

Directly injecting the dependency

```
struct Engine {
    func start() {
        print("Start")
    }

    func stop() {
        print("Stop")
    }
}

struct Car {
    let engine: Engine
    init(engine: Engine) {
        self.engine = engine
    }
}
```

Injecting a dependency that conforms to a protocol

```
protocol EngineProtocol {
    func start()
    func stop()
}

struct Engine: EngineProtocol {
    func start() {
        print("Start")
    }
    
    func stop() {
        print("Stop")
    }
}

struct Car {
    let engine: EngineProtocol
    init(engine: EngineProtocol) {
        self.engine = engine
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Dependency injection wise there is no difference. What you _can_ inject _might_ differ.

Comment: So when will I use one over another one? Any advantages?

Comment: In your first version there is no dependency injection at all . Actually, you establish a direct dependency between two concrete types. **This is what you want to avoid with dependency injection.** In your second example, you provide _one way_ (of several) to _inject_ the dependency using the initialiser of the dependent type. This is considered to have more Pros than using a property, which holds the dependency, and which you inject after creation of the dependent object.

Comment: In general you should favour composition (protocol example) over inheritance (class example), but that is something which transcends dependency injection. Beside the protocol allowing for the concrete type implementing it to be composited, it also acts as another layer of abstraction, making `Car` not directly dependant on the implementation of the `Engine` class, but rather on an abstraction _representing_ an engine.

Note that in both cases you are doing dependency injection (you are injecting a dependency, concrete or not), you are not doing proper _dependency inversion_ however.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper ah yes of course, the struct is not polymorphic. You are correct here indeed.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans I deleted my comment, because there is (too much) room for opinions, because we might consider a variable _configuration_ of a monomorphic type being the material for an "injection".  ;)  In the OP's 1. case, it's IMHO not DI, but what if the Engine has itself DI? (like having a pointer to a `EngineBase` , etc.

Comment: Also, note that dependency injection doesn't work with structs, as structs are copied when passed downstream, thus you end up with two independent copies.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, Dependency injection is one of many ways to achieve Dependency Inversion Principle. DIP said that:

> A.High-level modules should not import anything from low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions (e.g., protocol).
> B.Abstractions should not depend on details. Details (concrete implementations) SHOULD DEPEND ON abstractions.

So in your first version, Car and Engine are depending by DETAILS, and they SHOULD NOT DEPEND ON DETAILS. By contrast, in your second version, they DEPEND ON abstractions (protocol). DI using protocol are useful for:

- Achieving a generic behavior where one can inject any type that conforms to a given protocol
- Ability to test the class using mocked injected parameters

Further more, using protocol can bring some advantages. You can read more at the link below:
https://medium.com/swlh/protocol-oriented-programming-benefits-2910e3c86c7b